# Replace existing thermostat with diy solution

Tags: thermostat

I currently have a wireless [Altech thermostat](https://www.dispart.fr/asset/43/19/AST134319.pdf). Is there any chance I can replace it with an diy solution (based for instance on a Raspberry Pi)? The idea will be to only replace the transmitter and keep the existing receiver. The frequency used is 868MHz.

I have not find any information about a specific protocol used by the Altech solution. So maybe there is a proprietary one.

Comment: It's almost certainly possible. 868MHz ISM band transmitters are not particularly rare, but reverse-engineering the protocol will probably hold you up some. But it's not clear what your *DIY/Home-Improvement* question is (since reverse-engineering radio protocols is more than a little off-topic here) ...

Comment: The idea will be to replace an existing wireless thermostat by an homemade one. I want to obtain a more powerful solution by adding (1) a webserver based home automation or (2) a more precise control of the heating. CurrentlyI will try to avoid to use a new relay on my boiler by using the existing one.

Answer (score 1):

Why be married to their weird proprietary radio scheme? WiFi is available for the Pi.

Put another Pi down on the furnace. For instance it can advertise (or better, *not* advertise) its own WiFi channel.

A thermostat is a simple switch.  Either it shorts two wires to call for heat, or it does not.

Now in America we would just do all this with 24VAC control voltage.  But since Europe uses 240V thermostat voltage* you need to switch whatever the rating of the supply fuse/circuit breaker is, e.g. 16 amps.   A relay that size probably has a large coil, too heavy for the Pi to operate (especially when inductive kick is considered).  So have the "Furnace Pi" operate a small pilot relay.  The pilot relay pulls in the coil of a much larger relay.

---

* so I guess that means Euro thermostats require Class I wiring to the 'stat? How inconvenient.  All the more reason to control the 'stat wirelesly.  Do the same with doorbells, while you're at it... 230V doorbells, **shudder**

Comment: A person shouldn't have to consider a doorbell to be a fire risk. *It just ain't right.*

Comment: @isherwood on the other hand - unwanted visitors...ZAP!